# Graphql query result comes back undefined

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, next.js, graphql-tag

I am getting the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'privateKey' of undefined`

Employee query result comes back undefined when trying to console.log `this.props.employee`

I am using Graphql and Next.js. Am unsure whether or not componentWillMount is the correct lifecyle method to use as `this.props.data.employee` is `undefined`.

```
    class EmployeeTable extends Component {
    state = {
        employeesList: [],
        privateKey: ""
    }

    fetchEmployees = async () => {
        console.log(this.props.data.employee);
        console.log(this.props.data.employee.privateKey);
        const adminWallet = new ethers.Wallet(this.state.privateKey, provider);
        const EmployeeStore = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, adminWallet);

        let count;
        await EmployeeStore.functions.employeesCount().then(function(value) {
        count = value;
        });

        let employeesList = [];
        for(let i = 1; i<=count; i++) {
            await EmployeeStore.getEmployeeByIndex(i).then(function(result) {
            employeesList.push(result);
        });
        };
        console.log(employeesList);
        return {employeesList}; 
    };


    componentWillMount = async () => {
        var employees = await this.fetchEmployees();
        this.setState({employeesList: employees});
    };  

    renderRows() {
        return this.state.employeesList.map((employee, index) => {
            return (<EmployeeRow
                key={index}
                employee={employee}
            />
            );
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { Header, Row, HeaderCell, Body } = Table;
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>Employees</h3>
                <Table>
                    <Header>
                        <Row>
                        <HeaderCell>Name</HeaderCell>
                        <HeaderCell>Employee ID</HeaderCell>
                        <HeaderCell>Address</HeaderCell>
                        <HeaderCell>Authenticated</HeaderCell>
                        </Row>
                    </Header>
                    <Body>{this.renderRows()}</Body>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const employee = gql`
query employee($employeeID: String){ 
    employee(employeeID: $employeeID) {
        privateKey
    }
}
`;

export default graphql(employee, {
    options: {
        variables: {employeeID: "1234"}
    },
  })
  (EmployeeTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time a component wrapped with a Query operation, like in your code, is rendered it receives the `data` prop but without the results yet.

`data` contains a field called `loading`. If it is set to `true`, it means the query didn't receive all the results from the server yet. If the operation is successful, next time your component is rendered `this.props.data` will have `loading === false` and `this.props.data.employee` should be have a value as you expect.

Basically, you should check if `this.props.data.loading` is `true` or `false` before calling `fetchEmployees()` and before rendering child components that rely on the results.